# Found a problem while trying to rotate a matrix 90 degrees n times in C

Tags: c, function, matrix, rotation, transpose

I got into some problem when I wanted to make a program in C that rotate 90 degrees counterclockwise a matrix that has a different value of row and column. This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void swap(int *x, int *y)
{
    int temp = *x;
    *x = *y;
    *y = temp;
}

void transpose(int row, int column, int matrix[row][column])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i; j < column; j++)
        {
            swap(&matrix[i][j], &matrix[j][i]);
        }
    }
}

void reverseColumns(int row, int column, int matrix[row][column])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < column; i++)
    {   
        for (int j = 0, k = column - 1; j < k; j++, k--)
        {    
            swap(&matrix[j][i], &matrix[k][i]);
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int row, column;
    scanf("%d %d", &row, &column);

    int matrix[row][column];
    for(int i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < column; j++)
        {
            scanf("%d", &matrix[i][j]);
        }
    }

    int rotation_times;
    scanf("%d", &rotation_times);
    rotation_times = rotation_times % 4;

    for(int i = 0; i < rotation_times; i++)
    {
        transpose(row, column, matrix);
        reverseColumns(row, column, matrix);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < column; j++)
        {
            printf("%d ", matrix[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I wanted to rotate a 2x3 sized matrix 2 times, this is the input:

```
2 3
1 1 1
2 3 4
2
```

This is the expected output:

```
4 3 2
1 1 1
```

And this is the actual output:

```
0 0 422510592
4 3 2
```

I'm trying to see what's wrong by printing 3 rows and 3 columns and this is what I got:

```
0 0 -2119237632
4 3 2
1 1 1
```

Does anyone know what happened and how to fix it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you expect to happen if you have a different number of rows and columns? How do you define the result of a rotation of 90° in that case? `swap(&matrix[i][j], &matrix[j][i]);` This will cause illegal access if `i` or `j` exceed the number of rows or columns.

Comment: But you *are* aware that transposed non-square matrices do not have the same dimensions as their respective original???

Comment: Transposing, by the way, is not the same as rotating...

Comment: If you `transpose` function you will swap some pairs of cells twice, e.g. for `i=1,j=2` and `i=2, j=1`

Comment: The expected output you show, “4 3 2” on line line followed by “1 1 1” on the next, is not a 90º rotation of the input, “1 1 1” and “2 3 4”. It is a 180º rotation. Is the statement you want a 90º rotation wrong or is the statement of the expected output wrong?

Comment: Rotating a m×n matrix 90º within memory of m×n elements is generally difficult, as the differently sized rows and columns interfere with each other. One solution is to rotate into a destination array separate from the source array. Another is to use a square array that is at least m×m or n×n, whichever is larger, leaving some elements unused. A third way is to move the elements using the memory permutation induced by the rotation, but this is cumbersome and may be challenging for novices.

Comment: In any case, you essentially need to rewrite your code from scratch. Rotation by transposition and reflection can work, but you need to manage the memory correctly.

Comment: Transposing a matrix in-place and rotating a matrix in-place are equally difficult, so it would seem to make sense to do the rotation in one go instead of transposing then flipping. It is easier to create the transposed or rotated matrix in a separate matrix rather than doing it in-place. If you must do it in-place, the simplest method is to "follow the cycles" and keep track of which elements have already been moved when looking for the next cycle after completing a cycle and there are more elements still to do. This needs 1 bit of temporary storage per element to indicate it has been moved.